# Can I configure Windows 10 Mail for my own server?

Tags: windows-10, email

Windows 10 has a fairly basic mail program built in.

It is easy to set it to collect email from GMail, Yahoo, etc

However, I have a server of my own, for which I would like to connect to with `Windows 10 Mail`.  That would require being able to configure authentication details, ports, etc

I can't immediately see how, nor does Google help.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

When you setup mail, you choose Pop3/imap, and it gives you 3 simple settings: Email address, Display name and password.

It will try to use autodiscover in order to automatically setup the mail. If this fails, it will ask you to enter the server, port and all other settings you seek.

However, if it does detect the settings and configure the mail for you, you will be able to edit the settings thereafter. Simply click the advanced settings to change the server settings. By default it should try secure first, so you may not need to change anything.

Comment: So close (+1), but although it allows me to enter my server as an IP address, which my ISP requires), it won't let me enter port numbers, which is a must :-(  Looks like I am out of luck

Comment: I configured an email for IMAP4 today on windows 10 Mail and I was able to change the ports. It is there! I believe you have to specify the port as follows: Server: example.com:993:1

Comment: That did it !  Plus one